How do I install a dotnet SDK/Targeting Pack for v4.7.2 in Github Actions?
I'm attempting to check that a C# project compiles as a pre-merge step in Github. This project integrates with a legacy system, and uses .NETFramework v4.7.2 as a target. My github action yaml is based on an example I found online, and looks like:
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT: 1
      DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE: 1
      DOTNET_NOLOGO: true
      DOTNET_GENERATE_ASPNET_CERTIFICATE: false
      DOTNET_ADD_GLOBAL_TOOLS_TO_PATH: false
      DOTNET_MULTILEVEL_LOOKUP: 0
      DOTNET_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_ALLOW_ANSI_COLOR_REDIRECTION: true
      TERM: xterm

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      
    - name: Setup .NET SDK
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
      with:
        dotnet-version: 8.0.204

    # Added this after first error, but it can not find 4.7.2
    - name: Setup .NET Framework
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
      with:
        dotnet-version: 4.7.2

    - name: Restore
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test

Without the second setup step, I get this error:

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.301/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1248,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [/home/runner/work/great-plains/great-plains/GreatPlainsConnector.Common/GreatPlainsConnector.Common.csproj]

With the second setup step, I get this error:

Error: Failed to install dotnet, exit code: 1. dotnet_install: Error: Could not find .NET Core SDK with version = 4.7.2

How can I install the v4.7.2 targeting pack in a Github action?

There isn't .NET Framework for Linux, so you should instead convert that legacy project to SDK style and then multi-targeting net472 and net8.0. On Linux, use MSBuild conditions to ignore net472.

Or runs-on: windows-latest

@LexLi Can you give me more details about what converting my project to "SDK style" means? After I multi-target net472 and net8.0, won't I still need to install the targeting pack on the Github build node?

That's why I said "On Linux, use MSBuild conditions to ignore net472"
